Is there a way to create a new command or something similar for \scalebox?
Every time I have to write in math mode but not in display mode (that is, when I write in math mode while writing a row of text) I find good to use \scalebox when dealing with fractions. What I write is usually \scalebox{1.2}{\( \frac{BLA}{BLABLA} \)}.
Is there a way to create a new command or similar to avoid to write all that every time? Notice that I only use scalebox for fractions, so it would be cool to have a command like \sf{}{} which stands for all the \scalebox{1.2}{\( \frac{BLA}{BLABLA} \)}.
Notice that I know that I am destroying the line spacing with this because FRAC or DFRAC should be used since the do create fractions perfectly fitting, but I realised that spacing is nothing I care about, rather than reading well a fraction.
Thank you again

We need a Minimal (not?) Working Example.

well obviously you can define \newcommand\uglyfrak[2]{\scalebox{1.2}{\( \frac{#1}{#2} \)}} but why not use a proper display fraction rather than scaling an inline one???

\dfrac does not produce a fraction that fits the line spacing, it forces a display fracktion, but in a much more coherent way than scaling an inline fraction

@DavidCarlisle You're right, I'm sleepy

You can define a \newcommand for any fragment of tex code, there is nothing special about \scalebox or \frac.  However you would get a far more consistent font size by using \dfrac which would use the normal text size letters in the numerator rather than 1.2 scaled scriptsize (which in most classes is 1.2*0.7 =0.84 scaled textsize which is a size unused elsewhere in the document.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\newcommand\uglyfrak[2]{\scalebox{1.2}{\( \frac{#1}{#2} \)}}

\begin{document}



abc \(x + \frac{a+b}{c} + \dfrac{a+b}{c} + \uglyfrak{a+b}{c}\) abc

\end{document}

As you see, not only does the scaled version use an inconsistent font size and rule width, the alignment is off, the rule should be on the math axis matching the horizontal bar of the +

Never use \scalebox with text or math (with possible exceptions for very particular cases, among which you don't find typesetting inline material).
If you're fine with spoiling the line spacing, you can use nccmath.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}

\begin{document}

abc \(x + \frac{a+b}{c} + \mfrac{a+b}{c} + \dfrac{a+b}{c}\) abc

\end{document}


Just to show why you shouldn't, try with
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[45][1-4] \(x + \frac{a+b}{c}\) \lipsum[49][1-4]

\lipsum*[45][1-4] \(x + \mfrac{a+b}{c}\) \lipsum[49][1-4]

\end{document}


Of course, you should be using (a+b)/c. Anyway, if you have several instances of inline fraction you don't want to render in the slashed form, the only sensible thing to do is to increase the leading.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[45][1-4] \(x + \frac{a+b}{c}\) \lipsum[49][1-4]

\lipsum*[45][1-4] \(x + \mfrac{a+b}{c}\) \lipsum[49][1-4]

\end{document}


You see that \frac produces an acceptable result, but \mfrac doesn't. And it doesn't really improve readability.
